# Summarizing log file to unique entries only

Tags: python, perl

I have been using this script for years at work to summarize log files.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 $logf = '/var/log/messages.log';

 @logf=( `cat $logf` );
 foreach $line ( @logf ) {
      $line=~s/\d+/#/g;
      $count{$line}++;
 }

 @alpha=sort @logf;
 $prev = 'null';
 @uniq = grep($_ ne $prev && ($prev = $_), @alpha);
 foreach $line (@uniq) {
      print "$count{$line}: ";
      print "$line";
 }
```

I have wanted to rewrite it in Python but I do not fully understand certain portions of it, such as:

```
 @alpha=sort @logf;
 $prev = 'null';
 @uniq = grep($_ ne $prev && ($prev = $_), @alpha);
```

Does anyone know of a Python module that would negate the need to rewrite this?  I haven't had any luck find something similar.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best way of understanding it would be to take the bits you dont understand and put print statements in. ``@alpha = sort @logf`` sorts the logf rows into an array calle alpha.

Comment: You should show an example of the output as this is doing more that sort uniquely a log file, it's kill numbers, probably the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @alpha=sort @logf;
 $prev = 'null';
 @uniq = grep($_ ne $prev && ($prev = $_), @alpha);
```

would be equivalent to

```
uniq = sorted(set(logf))
```

if `logf` were a list of lines.

However, since you are counting the freqency of lines,
you could use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to both count the lines and collect the unique lines (as keys) (thus removing the need to compute `uniq` at all):

```
count = collections.Counter()
for line in f:
    count[line] += 1
```

---

```
import sys
import re
import collections

logf = '/var/log/messages.log'
count = collections.Counter()
write = sys.stdout.write

with open(logf, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r'\d+','#',line)
        count[line] += 1

for line in sorted(count):
     write("{c}: {l}".format(c = count[line], l = line))
```

Comment: They're not 100% equivalent - remove ``\`` on ``#`` - also uniq should be sorted. As in the Perl @alpha was sorted.

Comment: @sotapme, The sorting appears to me to be a means to finding the unique elements rather than a goal because it would make probably make more sense to sort by count.

Comment: I was just running each version against each other to make sure they were the same. Now they're byte perfect!, well without ``\``# they are. Usually when working with logfile it's not good to load them into memory as they can be huuuuuge.

Answer (score 3):

As the name of the var implies,

```
@alpha=sort @logf;
$prev = 'null';
@uniq = grep($_ ne $prev && ($prev = $_), @alpha);
```

is finding unique elements (i.e. removing duplicate lines), ignoring numbers in the line since they were previously replaced with `#`. Those three lines could have been written

```
@uniq = sort keys(%count);
```

or maybe even

```
@uniq = keys(%count);
```

Another way of writing the program in Perl:

```
my $log_qfn = '/var/log/messages.log';
open(my $fh, '<', $log_qfn)
   or die("Can't open $log_qfn: $!\n");

my %counts;
while (<$fh>) {
   s/\d+/#/g;
   ++$counts{$_};
}

#for (sort keys(%counts)) {
for (keys(%counts)) {
   print "$counts{$_}: $_";
}
```

This should be easier to translate into Python.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I often encountered with people trying to do stuff in python perl can be done in one line on shell or bash:

I don't care for downvotes, since people should know there is no reason to do stuff in 20 lines of python if it can be done on shell

```
< my_file.txt | sort | uniq > uniq_my_file.txt
```

Comment: as ikegami says it's not equivalent also ``sort -u myfile.txt > uniq_my_file.txt`` is better

Comment: I agree with what 0x90 says - usually one would do something like ``cut -c20- my.log | sort | uniq -c`` to show unique lines from the logs ignoring the date at the beginning of each line. That's why the numbers are being killed in the Op's version so that they don't upset each lines uniqueness.